# How can I swallow a whole cockatrice?

Tags: nethack

One possible death reason in NetHack is "petrified by swallowing a cockatrice whole".

However, when polymorphed into a purple worm and attacking a cockatrice, simply biting it the first time instakills me, giving just the normal "petrified by a cockatrice" death reason. How can I die after swallowing the cockatrice instead of just when I take a bite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use an engulfing attack on the cockatrice. [Purple worms have both a Bite attack and an Engulf attack](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Purple_worm). My guess is that since it seems like you used the Bite attack, the bite caused you to be petrified before you had a chance to actually engulf the cockatrice.

As an alternative, [trappers and lurkers above](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Trapper) will also work, as their sole attack is an engulf attack. (Lots of other monsters have engulfing attacks as well, but everything aside from the aforementioned three types are petrification-resistant, which you obviously don't want for this.)

Comment: Using a `t` seems to work flawlessly; attempting to get a purple worm lifesaved on the bite attack then proceed to the engulf attack was my first thought, which failed horribly. Now... to try to set myself up with a polykit in the devnull tournament so I can get this unique death :)